# ArcGIS 10 Add-In Does not Work on Other computers

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, add-in, visual-studio

I developed a user form that allows user to edit feature attributes in visual basic 2008. vb.net. The add-in's that I built work great on my computer, but when I tried it on another, it crashes ArcMap.

is this because the DeveloperKit is not installed on the other computer?

---

I manually add-in the tool (i.e., Customize, Add from file, etc) and it looks like it installs. ArcMap crashes when I click on the button though.  On my computer it work correctly using the same method.

I have uploaded the file to here: http://wfurl.com/3611b10

Comment: Does it crash ArcMap while it starting up? Or once ArcMap is up and running and you try to use an AddIn component(button/tool/dockable window)?

Comment: The SDK is not required to run add-ins. Something else is causing the crash, but you'll have to elaborate on your question for anyone to be able to suggest how to fix it. Ideally post your VS solution to someplace like [smartbins.net](http://www.smartbins.net).

Comment: Edited question to link to code

Comment: My guess is it has to do with the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs` dependency. Likely your clients' machines don't have it installed. See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbpowerpacks/thread/fd0f89a3-2a2c-4df0-9b84-3eeffde7fd2a

Comment: clients machine doesn't even have the \Microsoft SDK folder. I'll try installing it to see if it works

Comment: I think the suggestion was to install the PowerPacks bootstrapper thingy, not the Microsoft SDK (a hefty download IIRC). Better yet would be to remove the dependency if you aren't making use of it.

Comment: I think it is best practice to have a try/catch surrounding whatever you're doing in the Button's OnClick.  Also should call ReleaseComObject on your cursor at some point.

Comment: I don't know about the PowerPacks dependency, but I had issue with an ODP.NET dependency on machines that didn't have it or an Oracle client.  ArcMap would crash while starting...even if it was just a single using statement to the Oracle.DataAccess in a class...before any code was executed. What a pain it was to troubleshoot.   I ended invoking the object directly and casting to a System.Data interface because I didn't want ArcMap to be disabled just because my AddIn was installed.

Comment: Note that .NET loads assemblies in a very well defined fashion. Typically, before a method executes, all the dependent types (and their assemblies) are loaded. So it makes sense to wrap code in OnClick in a separate method so that you know when an assembly load exception occurs.

Comment: Of course, if you have private fields (or static fields) with a type which needs to be loaded from a dependent assembly, your class will fail to be instantiated (or its type loaded) completely. Most of the time, ArcGIS will silently swallow this error. This means you need to be especially aware of every dependency you introduce in your code.

Comment: Looks like the answer was the powerpacks...I had a line and a box on my user form; when removed it work on other computers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>(Months later...)</sub>

The answer is to not reference 3rd party dependencies if they aren't on the clients' machines and you aren't distributing them with your add-in. In this case it was the [Visual Basic Power Packs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb735936) dependency, which from the sounds of it wasn't being used anyways.

You should also be sure to implement error handling at all entry points to your add-in so that the host ArcGIS application does not swallow the errors or crash.