# ArcGIS 10 Addin Code Doesn't Execute on Another Computer?

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, add-in, visual-studio

I've created an ArcGIS 10 Addin that consists of a toolbar containing one button and one tool. The button opens a form, and the tool is disabled until the user enters some information on the form.

This addin works great on my development computer and on other computers in my office. But when I deliver the addin to the client, toolbar is there with the button and tool, but when he clicks the button, nothing happens. Not knowing if this had something to do with the form, I added a third button to the toolbar which displays a simple message when the button in clicked. For the client, a click on this button also results in nothing happening. The addin was created using vb.net and Visual Studio 2010.

I've checked that he has the same ArcGIS 10 service pack installed that I have, and that he has the correct .net framework installed. What else could be missing on his computer?

Comment: Does your add-in project have any unusual references that may be missing on the client's machine? See this question for an example: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18635/arcgis-10-add-in-does-not-work-on-other-computers

Answer (score 1):

The tool may be dependent on particular dev libraries that hasn't been ported over to the directory with files being operated on.